# How can I generate cod and alx files of blackberry application through command prompt?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to generate cod and alx files for blackberry application through command prompt.what are the steps to generate it?In order to build the application through command prompt what build items are required?The application is being developed for Blackberry torch 9800

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are are happy with ANT I would recommend using Blackberry ANT tools http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/

Comment: even assuming you aren't happy with ant! Use it.

Answer (score 0):

We use antenna (http://antenna.sourceforge.net/) and bb-ant-tools (http://bb-ant-tools.sourceforge.net/), we compile different bb os and devices same time with obfuscation.